# GITLAB-CI: Changing a version in a file / writing to a file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am fairly new to gitlab-ci and was wondering if something like this is possible to do in gitlab-ci, since i know it is possible to do in jenkins.

Basically, what i want to do is when a tag arrives i want to do a deploy (clean:deploy), however before i do that i want to enter the pom.xml and change a variable in there. My project is dependant on another project and i want to increment the other projects version. So this is what my pom would look like:

```xml
<!-- some pom stuff -->

<other.project.version>1.0.2</other.project.veresion>

<!-- some more pom stuff -->
```

Before i do the clean:deploy, i want to enter the pom and increment `other.project.version`. Then commit it and do the realase.

Is this possbile? What should i use? Are there any alternatives. Anything will help! Tnx guys.

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11952/gitlab-make-commit-in-shared-ci-runner-and-push-to-repository-open-merge-requ

Comment: @oakad based on the answer you sent me, i should create a script .sh script that will change the version in the pom and then commit it. I will deal with the push access tokens when i get there. Is this correct?

Comment: The example in the chosen answer shows how to push. Inspect the .gitlab-ci.yml there. Everything else is up to you: what to push, when, why.

Comment: @oakad yes, that is all well, however my specific problem is editing the file, specifically a specific portion of the file. Right now, i manually enter the file and edit it before pushing, but now i somehow need to make this automatic. In other words, how do i change `other.project.version` from 1.0.2 to 1.0.3 automaticly.